# Como posso adicionar uma variavel dentro de uma string utilizando a linguagem C?

Tags: c

No meu código, preciso inserir dentro de uma instrução SQL a data formatada como string utilizando este formato:

```
14/06/2020 - 20h40
```

Mas eu recebo os valores (minutos, horas, dias, meses, anos) separados (um valor em cada variável).

Como posso inserir estas variáveis dentro da string deste modo:

```
char *sql = "INSERT INTO register VALUES('Luis', '<dia>/<mes>/<ano> - <horas>h<minutos>');";
```

Caso não for possível inserir uma variável desse modo, existe alguma alternativa?

Comment: Você pode utilizar a função `sprintf`para gerar a string desejada. `sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO register VALUES('Luis', '%.2d/%.2d/%.4 - %.2dh%.2d');", dia, mes, ano, horas, minutos);`. Não se esqueça de reservar espaço pra a string.

Comment: @anonimo Seria melhor colocar esse comentário como resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duvida respondida com o comentário anônimo abaixo da minha publicação, obrigado!

```
sprintf(sql, "INSERT INTO register VALUES('Luis', '%.2d/%.2d/%.4 - %.2dh%.2d');", dia, mes, ano, horas, minutos);
```